# Edit sendmail /etc/aliases not working

Tags: linux, centos-7, sendmail

I'm using sendmail to send the server (centos 7) root system mails in a external gmail account, but the amount of mails i get is massive, but only a few are actually needed. In this particular case i would like to send only ssh alerts to a external gmail account. I edited my /etc/aliases to test this, but the second mail is not getting any mails from the server.

```
mailer-daemon:  postmaster
postmaster:     root
mailnull:   root
postgres:   root
sshd:       root, test
decode:         root
root: example@gmail-domain.com
test: example2@gmail-domain.com
```

And run `newaliases` afterwards, but only the root mails are working.

UPDATE: after running `sendmail -d27.2 -bv sshd` i get:

```
alias(sshd)
sshd (, sshd) aliased to root, test
self_reference(root)
... no self ref
self_reference(test)
... no self ref
alias(test)
test (, test) aliased to example2@gmail-domain.com
self_reference(example2@gmail-domain.com)
... no self ref
alias(root)
forward(root)
include(/root/.forward.HDRedirect-LB3-890977680)
include(/root/.forward)
root... deliverable: mailer local, user root
example2@gmail-domain.com... deliverable: mailer relay, host smtp.gmail.com, user example2@gmail-domain.com
```

Comment: What is reported by `sendmail -d27.2 -bv sshd` executed by root? [-d27.2 turns on tracing alias expansions see TRACEFLAGS file]

Comment: @AndrzejA.Filip i added the results in the post

Answer (score 0):

The alias is expanded properly according to results produced by `sendmail -d27.2 -bv sshd` executed by root.

It seem that you use gmail as authenticated smart host (smtp.gmail.com) and it does not work.

As root send test message in verbose mode (with full smtp session tracking):

```
(echo subject: test; echo ; echo test) | sendmail -i -v example2@gmail-domain.com
```

Comment: I'm getting this test mail, as i said, root mails are being sent and received, but the "test alias" are not